# How to count incident per group and entity

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following SQL structure and data :

**incident_1month**

| id | new_group | date_c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | '2023-02-01 07:16:00' |
| 2 | 3 | '2023-02-01 14:48:00' |
| 3 | 3 | '2023-02-02 18:05:00' |
| 4 | 4 | '2023-02-06 11:31:00' |
| 5 | 4 | '2023-02-08 07:11:00' |
| 6 | 4 | '2023-02-14 09:39:00' |

**incident_2month**

| id | new_group | date_c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | '2023-02-01 07:16:00' |
| 2 | 3 | '2023-02-01 14:48:00' |
| 3 | 3 | '2023-02-02 18:05:00' |
| 4 | 4 | '2023-02-06 11:31:00' |
| 5 | 4 | '2023-02-08 07:11:00' |
| 6 | 4 | '2023-02-14 09:39:00' |
| 7 | 4 | '2023-01-14 09:39:00' |
| 8 | 1 | '2023-01-14 09:39:00' |
| 9 | 2 | '2023-01-14 09:39:00' |
| 10 | 2 | '2023-01-14 09:39:00' |

**persongroup**

| id | entity_c | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 'GRP1' |
| 2 | 2 | 'GRP2' |
| 3 | 3 | 'GRP3' |
| 4 | 4 | 'GRP4' |
| 5 | 5 | 'GRP5' |
| 6 | 6 | 'GRP6' |

**entity**

| id | displaylabel |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 'entite1' |
| 2 | 'entite2' |
| 3 | 'entite3' |
| 4 | 'entite4' |
| 5 | 'entite5' |
| 6 | 'entite6 |

**Schema**

[image]

**Context**

I'm trying to count the number of incident which occur on table `incident_1month` and `incident_1month` per group and entity.
I've come up to the following query :

```
SELECT 
    "persongroup"."name" AS "Groupe", 
    "entity"."displaylabel" AS "Entity",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN "persongroup"."id" IN (SELECT new_group FROM incident_1month) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "Number of incident 1 month",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN "persongroup"."id" IN (SELECT new_group FROM incident_2month) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "Number of incident 2 month"
FROM 
    "persongroup" 
LEFT JOIN 
    "entity" ON "persongroup"."entity_c" = "entity"."id" 
GROUP BY "persongroup"."name", "entity"."displaylabel"
ORDER BY "persongroup"."name"
```

Output :

| Groupe | Entity | Number of incident 1 month | Number of incident 2 month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GRP1 | entite1 | 1 | 1 |
| GRP2 | entite2 | 0 | 1 |
| GRP3 | entite3 | 1 | 1 |
| GRP4 | entite4 | 1 | 1 |
| GRP5 | entite5 | 0 | 0 |
| GRP6 | entite6 | 0 | 0 |

Expected output :

| Groupe | Entity | Number of incident 1 month | Number of incident 2 month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GRP1 | entite1 | 1 | 2 |
| GRP2 | entite2 | 0 | 1 |
| GRP3 | entite3 | 2 | 3 |
| GRP4 | entite4 | 3 | 4 |
| GRP5 | entite5 | 0 | 0 |
| GRP6 | entite6 | 0 | 0 |

I don't understand why, my count can't be more than `1`.

Demo : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/24ehsi3qa7fcvVFEcYd323/3

Comment: Your query only counts one because it's iterating over the table persongroup only (which I assume to have no duplicates) ... i.e. the `CASE` condition is only evaluated for each row in the table `persongroup`, resulting in `1` if the group have one or more incidents in the target table ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use correlated subqueries with out the grouping you get your wanted result

you count actually doesn't count the occurances of the id, it only count if it is there in the tables incident_2month  and incident_1month

```
SELECT 
    "persongroup"."name" AS "Groupe", 
    "entity"."displaylabel" AS "Entity",
    (SELECT COUNT(new_group) FROM incident_1month i WHERE i.new_group = "persongroup"."id")  AS "Number of incident 1 month",
    (SELECT COUNT(new_group) FROM incident_2month i WHERE i.new_group = "persongroup"."id") AS "Number of incident 2 month"
FROM 
    "persongroup" 
LEFT JOIN 
    "entity" ON "persongroup"."entity_c" = "entity"."id" 
ORDER BY "persongroup"."name"
```

| Groupe | Entity | Number of incident 1 month | Number of incident 2 month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GRP1 | entite1 | 1 | 2 |
| GRP2 | entite2 | 0 | 1 |
| GRP3 | entite3 | 2 | 3 |
| GRP4 | entite4 | 3 | 4 |
| GRP5 | entite5 | 0 | 0 |
| GRP6 | entite6 | 0 | 0 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fPGayhaD)

You could join the already counted number

```
SELECT 
    "persongroup"."name" AS "Groupe", 
    "entity"."displaylabel" AS "Entity",   
    COALESCE(m1.num,0) AS "Number of incident 1 month",
    COALESCE(m2.num,0) AS "Number of incident 2 month"
FROM 
    "persongroup" 
LEFT JOIN 
    "entity" ON "persongroup"."entity_c" = "entity"."id" 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(*) num , new_group FROM incident_1month GROUP BY new_group) m1 ON m1.new_group = "persongroup"."id"
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(*) num , new_group FROM incident_2month GROUP BY new_group) m2 ON m2.new_group = "persongroup"."id"
--GROUP BY "persongroup"."name", "entity"."displaylabel"
ORDER BY "persongroup"."name"
```

| Groupe | Entity | Number of incident 1 month | Number of incident 2 month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GRP1 | entite1 | 1 | 2 |
| GRP2 | entite2 | 0 | 1 |
| GRP3 | entite3 | 2 | 3 |
| GRP4 | entite4 | 3 | 4 |
| GRP5 | entite5 | 0 | 0 |
| GRP6 | entite6 | 0 | 0 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/h6373w8S)